# Simple Powershell IIS Site Verification

Tags: powershell

part of our checkout process after patching is checking webservers.  I'd like create a for each loop that runs the following script looking for 200 or 401 and pops terminal message a "site ok message" with the site name. If it gets anything else, I'd like an error message that gives the site name as well.

I know 401 response isn't really ok, but some of the sites I manage I don't have rights to view.  (Hence is why I wanted to go this route, I never know what "looks right" on a visual check.  Here is what I have so far.

```
    $HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('https://someinternalserver.com')
    $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
    $HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode

            If ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) {
            Write-output $http_request | Select-Object RequestUri
            Write-Host "SITE OK! 200"

            If ($HTTP_Status -eq 401) {
            Write-output $http_request | Select-Object RequestUri
            Write_Host "SITE OK! 401"}
        }

        Else {
            Write-output $http_request | Select-Object RequestUri
            Write-Host "SITE DEAD"}

     If ($HTTP_Response -eq $null) { } 

     Else { $HTTP_Response.Close() }
```

When I run the command, I am getting error messages that I don't really care about on line 5.  How do I supress them?  Ideally I am trying to make it look clean as I can so we can just watch info scroll by and note any server that is something other than 200 or 401[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6F9b.png)

...this was working too sort of but now I seem to have broken it to the point where everything comes back as SITE DEAD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a try/catch.

```
$HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('http://localhost:8080')
$HTTP_Response
$HTTP_Status
try {
    $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
    $HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode
}
catch {

}
If ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) {
    Write-output $http_request | Select-Object RequestUri
    Write-Host "SITE OK! 200"

    If ($HTTP_Status -eq 401) {
        Write-output $http_request | Select-Object RequestUri
        Write_Host "SITE OK! 401"
    }
}

Else {
    Write-output $http_request | Select-Object RequestUri
    Write-Host "SITE DEAD"
}

If ($HTTP_Response -eq $null) { } 
Else { $HTTP_Response.Close() }
```

If you want to hit some URLs in a loop, you can do something like this:

```
param(
    $urls = @('http://localhost:8080', 'https://google.com')
)

Clear-Host

foreach ($url in $urls) {
    $HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $HTTP_Response
    $HTTP_Status
    try {
        $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
        $HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode
    }
    catch {

    }
    If ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) {
        Write-Host ($http_request | Select-Object RequestUri).RequestUri
        Write-Host "SITE OK! 200 `n"
    }
    ElseIf ($HTTP_Status -eq 401) {
        Write-Host ($http_request | Select-Object RequestUri).RequestUri
        Write_Host "SITE OK! 401 `n"
    } 
    Else {
        Write-Host ($http_request | Select-Object RequestUri).RequestUri
        Write-Host "SITE DEAD `n"
    }

    # $null should be on the left: https://evotec.xyz/the-curious-case-of-null-should-be-on-the-left-side-of-equality-comparisons-psscriptanalyzer/
    If ($null -eq $HTTP_Response) { } 
    Else { $HTTP_Response.Close() }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Two questions, to nest this into a foreach loop, what would I do to the $HTTP_Request variable?  Also, it displays all the attributes for the Webrequest, is there anyway to mute that and get just name and status?

Comment: Awesome thanks so much, I was reading up on outputting to null, glad to know I was on the right path.  Thanks again!